# ios - How to initialize an array with names?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm new to iPhone development,I want to initialize strings in an array like the given format

```
-(IBAction)btnSubmit:(UIButton *)sender
{
NSString *phone = phoneNumber.text;
NSLog(@"Phone  :%@",phone);
NSString *TxtUserName = userName.text;
NSString *TxtEmailId = emailId.text;
NSArray *details = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:TxtUserName,TxtEmailId,phone,nil]; 
}
```

I'm getting details :(
    "xxxxxxx",
    "xxxxx@gmail.com",
    7675
)

I want to get details  :("Name=xxxx","Email=xxxx@gmail.com","Phone=8786")

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And if you want to add/delete entries during runtime, use `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: i am adding answer check it out....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either NSDictionary is what you need, however if you want in the format you have specified in the question:

```
NSString *phone = NSString stringWithFormat:@"Phone=%@",phoneNumber.text];
NSLog(@"Phone  :%@",phone);
NSString *TxtUserName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name=%@",userName.text];
NSString *TxtEmailId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email=%@",emailId.text];
NSArray *details = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:TxtUserName,TxtEmailId,phone,nil];
```

The other answers mentioned here deal with the part of using `NSDictionary`/`NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.....

Answer (score 3):

initialize `array` like

```
NSMutableArray *dummyArr = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[dummyArr addObject @"Adam"];
[dummyArr addObject @"John"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary`: can handle key value pair

Array can store only objects,what you need is key-value pair mechanism

Comment: +1 NSDictionary will allow you to use Key Value pairs.https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below...

```
   dictMut=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dictMut setObject:@"xxxx" forKey:@"Name"];
            [dictMut setObject:@"xxxx@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];
            [dictMut setObject:@"8786" forKey:@"phone"];


            NSMutableArray *temp=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [temp addObject:dictMut];
```

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"name": userName.text, @"email":emailId.text};
```

Or use `NSMutableDictionary` if you want to change the objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:@"John" forKey:@"Firstname"];
[dict setObject:@"Doe" forKey:@"Lastname"];
[dict setObject:@"info at objectgraph.com" forKey:@"Email"];

NSLog(@"%@", dict);

NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];

// values in foreach loop
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:TxtUserName forKey:@"Name"];
[dict setValue:TxtEmailId forKey:@"Email"];
```

to get it back:

```
[dict valueForKey:@"Name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

While using dictionary is a very good option creating a model class for storing user info would be more useful. You can create methods which would work on the data for more reusability and keeping things simple.

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *emailID;
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *phoneNumber;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name 
           emailID:(NSString *)emailID 
    andPhoneNumber:(NSString *)phoneNumber;
```

Create user instance and set the values

```
-(IBAction)btnSubmit:(UIButton *)sender
{
   User *user = [User new];
   user.name = userName.text;
   user.emailID = emailId.text;
   user.phoneNumber = phoneNumber.text;

   //Use this instance for your work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSDictionary for this type of work. You can do it using this two method.

```
NSDictionary * = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:userName.text,@"Name",emailId.text,@"Email",phoneNumber.text,@"phone" nil];
```

Or you can do it like this.

```
NSMutableDictionary *eventData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:userName.text,@"Name", nil];
[eventData setObject:emailId.text forKey:@"Email"];
[eventData setObject:phoneNumber.text forKey:@"phone"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

[dict setObject:@"Bob Jones" forKey:@"name"];
[dict setObject:@31337 forKey:@"number"];
[dict setObject:@"Turkey" forKey:@"location"];
```

OR, shorthand:

```
NSDictionary dict = @{@"name": @"Bob Jones", @"number": @31337, @"location": @"Turkey"};
```

The `@31337` is objective-c shorthand for `[NSNumber numberWithInt:31337]` and is needed because `NSDictionary` / `NSMutableDictionary` can only store `NSObject`-derived classes.

In the first example, you're defining a blank `NSMutableDictionary` and then adding stuff to it. In the second, you're creating a constant, immutable, unchangeable dictionary with some keys and values in it. Example 1 and example 2 have the same data in it, but you can add / delete stuff from the first example.

Also, `NSMutableDictionary` is a subclass of `NSDictionary`, which means you can pass it to functions that accept `NSDictionary`. You cannot cast the other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `NSDictionary` which will allow you to store the individual bits of data you require, but you might also want to follow the MVC-design pattern which is very important in the Cocoa and Cocoa Touch frameworks.

In the MVC design pattern the data you are attempting to represent is the *Model*, so if you are doing anything non-trivial with the data you will want to create one or more objects representing the data, which can then be passed around your app and used appropriately.

It would be declared something like:

MyModel.h:

```
@interface MyModel : NSObject

@property (strong, readwrite) NSString *username;
@property (strong, readwrite) NSString *phoneNumber;
@property (strong, readwrite) NSString *emailAddress;

@end
```

In the implementation file (`MyModel.m`) you don't even have to use `@synthesize` these days as Apple considers that to be too much typing.  Instead the modern clang compiler will auto-generate the backing instance variables on your behalf.  Just remember to reference these properties using `myobject.username` or `self.username` rather than simply `_username`.

You can then consider adding methods that allow the data to be manipulated.  In this way your allow your model to change over time without having to re-code significant parts of your app, which would otherwise rely on an `NSDictionary` with a fixed key name, which will simplify the maintenance of your app.

Answer (score 0):

First set your data to NSMutableDictionary.........

```
Dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [Dic setObject:@"xxxx" forKey:@"Name"];
            [Dic setObject:@"xxxx@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];
            [Dic setObject:@"8786" forKey:@"phone"];
```

And then get data from NSMutableDictionary....